# How to Hit External REST POST API in WordPress?

Tags: api

I am new to WordPress and I have a client requirement to hit their API, which accepts a POST request and I just can't find out the way to achieve this.
I have to add the chat bot which hits API whenever user presses enter and display response of API.

Comment: Can you elaborate? When do you need to hit the API? What's the full context here.

Comment: [`curl`](http://php.net/curl)?

Comment: check out again?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102855/385).

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has several functions for sending requests via PHP, including [`wp_remote_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post), which you can use to send a POST request to an API. Then you can use [`wp_remote_retrieve_body()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_retrieve_body) to handle the response. It would look something like:

```
$response = wp_remote_post( 'http://example.org/api' );
$api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
```

If you need to interact with the API via JavaScript, then WordPress doesn't get involved, and you would do it the same way you'd do it any any JavaScript application.